# converting large xml to csv

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I am wanting to convert a large amount of xml data near 600mb where i wont no its headers or root nodes I did try the following code but its complaining it does not no its root nodes. What is the most effiecent way of processiing a large file.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Projects\csvExport\csvExport\csvExport\bin\VLFLBNM7.xml", FileMode.Open))
{

            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            xRoot.ElementName = "ReportDetails";
            // xRoot.Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com";
            xRoot.IsNullable = true;

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sequence[]),xRoot);
            var data = (Sequence[])serializer.Deserialize(fs);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                List<string> ss = new List<string>();
                foreach (var point in item.SourcePath) ss.Add(point.X + "," + point.Y);
                list.Add(string.Join(",", ss));
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Projects\csvExport\csvExport\csvExport\bin\csvFile.csv", list);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message ?

Comment: Its just returning an empty file there is no error as such when i no the file is 600mb in size with valid schema

Comment: Did you try creating a sample xml file, like a root node A with 2 children B and C, where C has one child... adding some garbage text nodes and seeing if you still get nothing ?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine if your XML is having root node with Name "ReportDetails"

Sample XML file for this code to work should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ReportDetails>
<Sequence>
   <SourcePath>
      <X>samply x</X>
      <Y>xample y</Y>

   </SourcePath>
</Sequence>
</ReportDetails>
```

Your XML is missing "ReportDetails" which you have specified in code

```
 xRoot.ElementName = "ReportDetails";
```

Comment: Hi Sorry it does not im trying to create a generic routine to convert xml to csv this was a sample i found trying to mod to my needs